# How many prime numbers between 100 and 200 in python

Tags: python

So I'm new to python coming from a java background and it's hard for me to get use to python's syntax and scoping and loops etc. This was a question my instructor asked and I'm lost to what I'm doing wrong

**Q. write a function or just use some if-else statement to figure out how many prime numbers are there between 100 and 200**

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if(num % i) == 0:
                return True

def primeNumbers():
    count = 0

    for num in range(100, 200):
        prime = isPrime(num)
        if prime == True:
            count += 1
    
    print(count)

primeNumbers()
```

Comment: What is the *actual* and *specific* question / issue? There is a "Q" and some presented code.. perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more suitable if just looking for feedback.

Comment: Question: are you sure it's necessary to use `range(2, num)`? Do you think you could use a smaller range and still get the right answer?

Comment: There are non-Pythonic idioms in the code but this is a logic issue. isPrime is wrong. What happens when i == 2? The function returns True. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: _I'm lost to what I'm doing wrong_ Tell us what the code is doing that you believe is wrong.  Do you get an error?  Is a certain number identified as prime when it shouldn't be?

Comment: A simple implementation would be to use a sieve of eratosthenes up to 200 and up to 100 and subtract

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find prime numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564607/how-to-find-prime-numbers-in-python)

Comment: The function returns true when the number IS divisible by another number, which is the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your `isPrime` function is wrong. It returns `True` when the number is divisible (i.e. not prime), and never returns `False`. A fixed version would be:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

That being said, a more Pythonic (and PEP-8 compliant) version of your program could be:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False


def prime_numbers(start, end):
    count = 0
    for num in range(start, end):
        if is_prime(num):
            count += 1
    return count


print("The number of prime numbers between 100 and 200 is", prime_numbers(100, 200))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is actually returning the count of numbers that are not prime.
The `isPrime` function is return `True` if the number is divisible by
by a number between  2 and num.
The function should be:

```
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, round(num**0.5)+1): # No need to search up to num
            if(num % i) == 0:
                return False
        return True
    return False
```

Or print `100 - count` in your `primeNumbers` function.

You could also check out the sieve of Eratosthenes

Comment: I've edited the code to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

In `isPrime(num)`

```py
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if(num % i) == 0: # <-- this condition
                return True # <-- this return value
```

Notice that `if(num % i) == 0:`  checks that if the *remainder* of `num` divided by `i` is 0, meaning that you want to check that if `i` is divisible by `num`. But if that condition is true, then `num` is not a prime, so you have to `return False`. And if that condition is `False` for every `i` in `range(2, num)`, then you can be assured that `num` is a prime.

A little thing I want to point out is that if `i` is a divisor of `num` then `num/i` is also a divisor. So in reality you only want to check about from `2` to  `sqrt(num)` or `num ** 0.5`

Suggested code:

```py
def isPrime(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5)):
            if(num % i) == 0:
                return False
        reuturn True
    else:
        return False
```

p/s: As others have pointed out, you shouldn't really use the normal prime testing in this project, instead, use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)